# Elastic/Opensearch: HowTo create a new document from an _ingest/pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, pipeline, document, new-operator, opensearch

I am working with Elastic/Opensearch and want to **create a new document in a different index out of an _ingest/pipeline**
I found no help in the www...

All my documents (filebeat) get parsed and modified in the beginning by a pipline, lets say "StartPipeline".
Triggered by an information in a field of the incoming document, lets say "Start", I want to store that value in a special way by creating a new document in a different long-termindex - with some more information from the triggering document.

If found possibilities, how to do this manually from the console (update_by_query / reindex / painlesscripts) but it has to be triggered by an incoming document...

Perhaps this is easier to understand - in my head it looks like something like that.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/StartPipeline
{
  "description" : "create a document in/to a different index",
  "processors" : [ {
      "PutNewDoc" : {
        "if": "ctx.FieldThatTriggers== 'start'",
        "index": "DestinationIndex",
        "_id": "123",
        "document": { "message":"",
                      "script":"start", 
                      "server":"alpha
                      ...}
      }
  } ]
}
```

Does anyone has an idea?
And sorry, I am no native speaker, I am from Germany

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch or Opensearch? For Opensearch the Ingest APIs are described here: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/rest-api/ingest-apis/index/

Comment: I am using Opensearch and thanks for the link to the whole documentation - but where can I find the hint that solves my concrete problem?
The link tells about post, get, put etc. none of them can be used in/during a pipeline

Comment: The different processors documentation can be found in the [ES 7.10 documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/ingest-processors.html)